# Framework/tool for processing C++ unit tests with numerical output

Tags: c++, unit-testing, testing, computer-vision

I am working on a C++ application that uses computer vision techniques to identify various types of objects in a sequence of images. The (1000+) images have been hand-classified, so we have an XML file for each image containing a description of where the objects are actually located in the images.

I would like to know if there is a testing framework that can understand/graph results from tests that are numeric, in this case some measure of the error in the program's classification of the images, rather than just pass/fail style unit tests.

We would like to use something like CDash/CTest for running these automated tests, and viewing over time how improvements to the vision algorithms are causing the images to be more correctly classified.

Does anyone know of a tool/framework that can do this?

Comment: Hopefully someone will contradict me but it generally the case that testing frameworks are usually pretty general purpose. As such they don't provide support for specific kinds of calculations. You may need to write your own code for the assessment of the error in the calculations given the correct answer. If you can measure the error, you can then create tests based on whether the error is within a specified tolerance. You can then create a set of tests based on increasingly tight tolerances. Which will let you observe whether improvements are reducing the error in the calculations.

Comment: @Bowie Owens: Make it an answer, I will vote you up :)

Comment: What does the hand-classification include ? Is it segmentations or bounding boxes or object tags ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should distinguish between Unit testing and algorithm performance (=accuracy and/or speed) evaluation. You should apply both, but separately.

Unit testing should tell you whether your code does what it's supposed to be. Not sure if/how you can unit test the whole chain from a raw image to extracted objects, but you should be able to test the "units" (modules/methods/classes) individually that are combined to do the job. Unit tests should give you "fail" or "pass". If a speed optimization changes the code's behavior, the unit test should tell you this. For unit testing there are plenty of frameworks available (I like Google Test, but there are many others.)

Your question seems to aim more at the second part: evaluate the quality of your algorithm. I personally love [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) which is mainly intended as Java/.net Continuous Integration Server, but you can easily use it with C++ too. I wrote a few lines of code in our shop to output Google Test results in a TeamCity format making use of their [service API](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD4/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingTests). Each time someone checks in a new revision, TeamCity executes the build (which can be a Visual Studio solution, Ant, command line script or others.) The results are visible to all team mates through a nice web ui. Furthermore, you can report [custom build statistics](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD4/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-ReportingBuildStatistics). This can be used for anything like perfomance testing of your algorithms. You simply output a line like

```
##teamcity[buildStatisticValue key='detectedObjectsPercent' value='88.3']
```

on the console from your application (which must be configured to run in each build) and TeamCity will store these values and provide a nice graph (values over time) on the web user interface.

Don't forget to setup your custom chart as described [here](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD4/Custom+Chart).

I think TeamCity is really simple to setup, so just give it a try! I even like it if I work on a project just by myself!

Comment: +1 for mentioning TeamCity, it is really worth checking out. Last time I checked they offered free licenses for groups up to 20 devs.

Comment: thanks TeamCity was a breeze to set up, and seems to do what I need quite nicely :)

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is a typical computer vision/ image processing testing application framework. Although I have designed and used several such systems over the years, they were/are all proprietary.

Such a general purpose testing tool should have variable tolerances, different measures of Type I/II errors and error rates, total summaries and also case-by-case identification of problems. It should also provide different views to different users - for example, while debugging, a programmer needs different data than the release/project manager.
A DB driven back-end and automated test suits enhanced with statistical plots would be great too!

Unfortunately, I do not know of any such testing frameworks available.
I have always had it in my mind to start an open-source project for such a system, but time and resources are scarce, and I was never sure of the actual desirability of such a system (though I am quite sure that it can be made general purpose to suite the needs of many applications).
I would be very interested to know if there is real interest in such a system, it may get the wheels of this project moving...
I think you will have to write your own code at this time.